# Hexbin: apply function for every bin

Tags: r, data-visualization, binning

I would like to build the hexbin plot where for every bin is the "ratio between class 1 and class2 points falling into this bin" is plotted (either log or not).

```
x <- rnorm(10000)
y <- rnorm(10000)
h <- hexbin(x,y)
plot(h)
l <- as.factor(c( rep(1,2000), rep(2,8000) ))
```

Any suggestions on how to implement this? Is there a way to introduce function to every bin based on bin statistics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@cryo111's answer has the most important ingredient - `IDs = TRUE`. After that it's just a matter of figuring out what you want to do with `Inf`'s and how much do you need to scale the ratios by to get integers that will produce a pretty plot.

```
library(hexbin)
library(data.table)

set.seed(1)
x = rnorm(10000)
y = rnorm(10000)

h = hexbin(x, y, IDs = TRUE)

# put all the relevant data in a data.table
dt = data.table(x, y, l = c(1,1,1,2), cID = h@cID)

# group by cID and calculate whatever statistic you like
# in this case, ratio of 1's to 2's,
# and then Inf's are set to be equal to the largest ratio
dt[, list(ratio = sum(l == 1)/sum(l == 2)), keyby = cID][,
     ratio := ifelse(ratio == Inf, max(ratio[is.finite(ratio)]), ratio)][,
     # scale up (I chose a scaling manually to get a prettier graph)
     # and convert to integer and change h
     as.integer(ratio*10)] -> h@count

plot(h)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi! Sorry for the late reply. You solution totally works for random data, but with real data it has strange behavior - even if the bin contain the class 2 it's not displayed  the original image http://i42.tinypic.com/nqa8mb.png, and the modified one http://i42.tinypic.com/5cc5g1.png. The classes are imbalanced, so not too many of bins are occupied by one class. What can be a problem of such move of the bins to the bottom, but the actual class  is occurring in the top.

Comment: @JohnAmraph I'd suggest trying to filter the data down to a small reproducible example and posting that example in OP - I can't really tell from your description what's going on

Comment: if I do the code the way I have the data: dt = data.table(x, y, l = c(rep(1,2000),rep(2,8000)), cID = h@cID)
I will receive the figure like this http://postimg.org/image/ay34ykyfr/ suggesting that there is something incorrect with an index. I am trying to figure out what's wrong...

Comment: @JohnAmraph I should have ordered by `cID` to match the hexbin cells correctly - I edited the answer to fix that (using `keyby` instead of `by`)

Answer (score 1):

You can determine the number of class 1 and class 2 points in each bin by

```
library(hexbin)
library(plyr)
x=rnorm(10000)
y=rnorm(10000)
#generate hexbin object with IDs=TRUE
#the object includes then a slot with a vector cID
#cID maps point (x[i],y[i]) to cell number cID[i]
HexObj=hexbin(x,y,IDs = TRUE)

#find count statistics for first 2000 points (class 1) and the rest (class 2)
CountDF=merge(count(HexObj@cID[1:2000]),
              count(HexObj@cID[2001:length(x)]),
              by="x",
              all=TRUE
             )
#replace NAs by 0
CountDF[is.na(CountDF)]=0
#check if all points are included
sum(CountDF$freq.x)+sum(CountDF$freq.y)
```

But printing them is another story. For instance, what if there are no class 2 points in one bin? The fraction is not defined then.
In addition, as far as I understand `hexbin` is just a two dimensional histogram. As such, it counts the number of points that fall into a given bin. I do not think that it can handle non-integer data as in your case.